# How does pygame.sprite.Group() know which sprite group to call? Also calling the sprite group also calls the class?

Tags: python, oop, pygame

Hello i'm working on an AlienInvasion game and I'm a bit confused on the `pygame.sprite.Group`. How does it know which `pygame.sprite.Group()` to call?

I'm used to referencing classes like this.
`self.ship = Ship(self)`

but this one calls it like this.  How does it know which sprite group it is calling?  I currently only have 1 sprite group ATM so it makes sense, but what if i have more?
`self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()`

and then later i'm able to reference a method from it like this
`self.bullets.update()`

```
class AlienInvasion:
"""Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

def __init__(self):
    """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
    pygame.init()
    self.settings = Settings()

    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    self.ship = Ship(self)
    self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()


def _update_bullets(self):
    """update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets"""
    # update bullet positions 
    self.bullets.update()

class Bullet(Sprite):
"""A class to manage bullets fired from the ship"""

def __init__(self, ai_game):
    """Create a bullet object at the ship's current position."""
    super().__init__()
    self.screen = ai_game.screen
    self.settings = ai_game.settings
    self.color=self.settings.bullet_color
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

You're creating a new `Group` object and assigning it to the attribute `bullets` on the current object. The group doesn't know where it's referenced from. When you start adding sprites to it, it will keep track of those sprites. That's the job of a `Group` object, it's like a `list` or other container. A `Group` has some specialized methods though that let you interact with multiple sprites in one go (like `Group.update()`, which calls `update()` on each of the sprites it contains).

You don't show any code in your `Bullet` class that adds them to the `Group`. That means that your bullets are not actually going to be contained in the `Group` you've named `bullets` yet. Probably you should do that for each bullet, as it is created. You probably want something like this (docstrings removed for brevity):

```
class Bullet(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        super().__init__(ai_game.bullets)           # pass the group here!
        ... # do the rest of your initialization
```

The `Sprite.__init__` method accepts any number of arguments, which it expects to be `Group`s. It adds the newly created sprite to each of those groups, which sounds like exactly what you want.

The `Sprite` class has another useful method for interacting with `Group`s that you may want to use later in your code: `Sprite.kill()` removes the sprite from all of its groups, which is convenient if the sprite has ceased to be relevant to your game (e.g. a bullet that has missed its target and flown off the screen).

Comment: Ahh, @Blckknght thank you!  
i think i get it with your explanation.

Cause later i do this. 

def _fire_bullet(self):
  """Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group."""
  if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullets_allowed:
   new_bullet = Bullet(self)
   self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

Comment: Ah, yes, if you have that code you don't need to change `Bullet.__init__` (and I'd have assumed you had something like it if you hadn't shown the `Bullet` code). So it's just a question of understanding how the `Group` works, and I'm glad my explanation helped with that.